# IOS Distribution certificate expiring - Issue updates to existing applications

Tags: ios, app-store, certificate

I have a paid application in the App Store . Recently i got an email saying that my distribution certificate is expiring and needs to be renewed.
 
The Email was :
This certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days. To create a new certificate, visitCertificates, Identifiers & Profiles in Member Center.
My question is, after i renew it either by waiting the whole 30 days and then renewing it or by revoking it and requesting a new one, can i issue updates to the already present applications once i renew it? and how?

Comment: What did you to then? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure - either option is fine - either let it expire or renew now. You won't be able to submit any updates with an expired cert, but once renewed you are good to go. No problem updating already existing apps with the new certificate.

Comment: Hi... I am having a same problem. So as you are saying I just need to create New Distribution certificate now without waiting for 30 days and just need to give that new certificate to all the provisioning profiles that are using that certificate?

Comment: Thank you … that's a relief ! now @Manthan i guess what to do next is to renew it..install it and never minding anything else

Comment: How do you renew it? I have an iOS Distribution certificate expiring 29th January but only have two buttons available - 'revoke' or 'download'. Is there somewhere else (other than Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in the iOS Dev Center) I need to go to renew it?

Comment: @amergin I am guessing you already saw what happened. Either revoke and make a new one or wait until it expires then there will be a renew button. Am I right?

Comment: @Mayizar I'm afraid I don't remember what I did as this was 9 months ago. Every time I have to deal with the provisioning nonsense I just wing it! I have tried keeping copious notes but things have changed so much over the years that my notes are all useless.

Comment: So my distribution certificates where created on another machine(clients) and now i am renewing on my machine. Is it necessary that i use the same private key which was initially used or i can create a private key on my machine and then share it with my client?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create new distribution (and also development) certificate directly in Xcode.

1. Choose Xcode > Preferences.
2. Click Accounts at the top of the window.
3. Select the team you want update, and click Manage Certificates...
4. Press the + button and choose iOS Distribution